# Virtualbox - Kernel driver installed

Tags: macos, virtualization, virtualbox, monterey

I'm running VirtualBox 6.1.  After the upgrade to macOS Monterey, my VM's fail to start up with the error message

> Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

I tried reinstalling VirtualBox and, while that worked at the moment, the problem began again when I turned on my computer the next day.

Based on similar questions on this site, I checked System Preferences -> Security & Privacy.  However, there's no pending request from Oracle.

Comment: Output of `kextstat | grep -v 'com.apple'`?

Comment: `Executing: /usr/bin/kmutil showloaded
No variant specified, falling back to release
Index Refs Address            Size       Wired      Name (Version) UUID <Linked Against>`

Comment: Sorry, I misread the system version. I believe from macOS 11 Kernel extensions are deprecated; instead Apple wants people to use system extensions. So you will need to follow this guide to enable loading of kernel extensions: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/installing-a-custom-kernel-extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does Oracle claim VirtualBox supports Monterey?  It seems not, although there are workarounds.

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=104272&sid=69ae383878d1d0b9a0e676592adeb79a

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error. I then ran `sudo kmutil load -p '/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/VBoxDrv.kext'` and the error went away.

Comment: Huh.  That worked!  What exactly did that do?

Comment: Also, I have to re-run that command whenever I restart my host computer.

Answer (score 3):

With an update to Virtualbox 6.1.30 macOS Monterey is supported. This [includes headless operation from posts on their beta forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?p=508251#p508251).